# convert list of tuple () to numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I want to convert a list of tuple like `a = [(1,2),(2,49),(3,45)]`

to numpy matrix : `[[1,2],[2,49],[3,45]]`

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: `np.asarray(a)`? You should really read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html) or [a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_ndarray_object.htm)

Comment: `np.array(...)` treats a list of tuples the same as a list of lists (unless you specify a compound dtype).

Answer (score -1):

try this:

a = [(1,2),(2,49),(3,45)]

print map(list,a)